# the meaning of "one of which" in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I read the novel "What ever happened to Baby Jane?". There's a phrase I'm not quite sure.

> The untended oleander bushes, **one of which** stood beside the shallow porch **of each unit**, were scraggly and shapeless, their leaves dingied over with dust and soot.

At the very first place, I thought "one of which" means; one of the many bushes. But the next semi-sentence made me confused because it said "of each unit (apartment)". So is it mean "each one of the bushes stood beside the shallow porch of each one of the unit?"

Comment: Quite simply, each porch had one bush beside it.

Comment: Thanks Kate for confrim my thought. When it was written "one of which" I thought it's "single one of the bushes", and imply "just only one bush besides one porch while the other porches have no bush".

Comment: @HyperHanabi In most contexts, if a pronoun is introduced in the middle of text, you can assume that it refers to something that was mentioned earlier in the text rather than to something that has not yet been mentioned at all. This is particularly true of *one of which*. In fact, I can think of no example of *one of which* where it could sensibly refer to something that has not yet been introduced. As part of a nonrestrictive relative clause, I believe it always refers backwards to a previously used noun.